# Issues in fitting data to linear model

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Assuming a noiseless AR(1) process `y(t)= a*y(t-1)` . I have following conceptual questions and shall be glad for the clarification.

Q1 - Discrepancy between mathematical formulation and implementation - The mathematical formulation of AR model is in the form of `y(t) = - summmation over i=1 to p[a*y(t-p)]  + eta(t)` where p=model order and `eta(t)` is a white gaussian noise. But when estimating coefficients using any method like `arburg()` or the least square, we simply call that function. I do not know if a white gaussian noise is implicitly added. Then, when we resolve the AR equation with the estimated coefficients, I have seen that the negative sign is not considered nor the noise term added.

What is the correct representation of AR model and how do I find the average coefficients over k number of trials when I have only a single sample of 1000 data points?

Q2 - Coding problem in How to simulate fitted_data for k number of trials and then find the residuals - I fitted a data "data" generated from unknown system and obtained the coefficient by

```
load('data.txt');

for trials = 1:10

    model = ar(data,1,'ls');
    original_data=data;

    fitted_data(i)=coeff1*data(i-1); %  **OR**
    data(i)=coeff1*data(i-1); 

    fitted_data=data;

    residual= original_data - fitted_data;
    plot(original_data,'r'); hold on; plot(fitted_data);

end
```

When calculating residual is the fitted_data obtained as above by resolving the AR equation with the obtained coefficients? Matlab has a function for doing this but I wanted to make my own. So, after finding coefficients from the original data how do I resolve ? The coding above is incorrect. Attached is the plot of original data and the fitted_data.[image: Plot of original vs fitted data]

Comment: Fitting data to model a path to the dark side it is, young padawan. Rather attempt you should fitting a model to your data...

Comment: the code you posted is confusing, for instance you are using index i at some point. Please post matlab code or explain that you are posting pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AR-type models can serve a number of purposes, including linear prediction, linear predictive coding, filtering noise. The eta(t) are not something we are interested in retaining, rather part of the point of the algorithms is to remove their influence to any extent possible by looking for persistent patterns in the data.

I have textbooks that, in the context of linear prediction, do not include the negative sign included in your expression prior to the sum. On the other hand Matlab's function `lpc`does:

```
Xp(n) = -A(2)*X(n-1) - A(3)*X(n-2) - ... - A(N+1)*X(n-N)
```

I recommend you look at function `lpc` if you haven't already, and at the [examples](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/lpc.html) from the documentation such as the following:

```
randn('state',0);
noise = randn(50000,1);  % Normalized white Gaussian noise
x = filter(1,[1 1/2 1/3 1/4],noise);
x = x(45904:50000);
% Compute the predictor coefficients, estimated signal, prediction error, and autocorrelation sequence of the prediction error: 
p = lpc(x,3);
est_x = filter([0 -p(2:end)],1,x);    % Estimated signal
e = x - est_x;                        % Prediction error
[acs,lags] = xcorr(e,'coeff');        % ACS of prediction error
```

The estimated `x` is computed as `est_x`. Note how the example uses `filter`. Quoting the matlab doc again, `filter(b,a,x)` "is a "Direct Form II Transposed" implementation of the standard difference equation:

```
a(1)*y(n) = b(1)*x(n) + b(2)*x(n-1) + ... + b(nb+1)*x(n-nb)
                      - a(2)*y(n-1) - ... - a(na+1)*y(n-na)
```

which means that in the prior example `est_x(n)` is computed as

```
  est_x(n) = -p(2)*x(n-1) -p(3)*x(n-2) -p(4)*x(n-3)
```

which is what you expect!

**Edit:**

As regards the function `ar`, the matlab [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/ident/ref/ar.html) explains that the output coefficients have the same meaning as in the lp scenario discussed above.

The right way to evaluate the output of the AR model is to compute

```
data_armod(i)= -coeff(2)*data(i-1) -coeff(3)*data(i-2) -coeff(4)*data(i-3)
```

where coeff is the coefficient matrix returned with

```
 model = ar(data,3,'ls');
 coeff = model.a;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and information about lpc,I was not aware of it. I still want to clarify what I did is correct or not using AR. In my code,is it incorrect to do data=original_data; %Find coefficients by model.a = ar(data,3,'ls'); % Estimate by resolving the equation; data(i)=coeff1*data(i-1)*coeff2*data(i-2) *coeff3*data(i-3) in order to find the estimated output?Then the residual would be e=original_data-data ?

Comment: Thank you.I wanted to accept both the answers..but it is strange that only one can be ticked off.Your replies to all my questions have been really helpful.

Comment: One last thing though,the eta(t) in mathematical expression is NOT the residual but a noise term.So,is it possible to determine what the value of distribution it is?

Comment: Note my final edit: I changed the sign of the coefficients to match matlab's convention.

Comment: Yeah, I admit it's not always fair with the tick marking. You can always click on the "up arrow" instead, it's almost as good, if not as satisfying :>)

Comment: Unless you know the underlying model EXACTLY, you can only estimate uncertainties, and presumably also the "noise" from your residuals.

Comment: So, are the residuals= data=data_armod?What do you mean by noise from residuals?Is residuals=noise that is mentioned in the mathematical expression, That is y(t) = - summmation over i=1 to p[a*y(t-p)] + residuals(t) ?? I am now confused since I had posted a question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65990/conceptual-issues-in-linear-modeling?noredirect=1#comment127474_65990 the answer to it says that the residuals are NOT the noise/error that is often represented in the equation.

Comment: Yes, `residuals = data -data_armod` (where you have to keep track of the indices because `data_armod` will not be of the same size as `data`, rather `length(data)`=`length(data_armod)+np`, where np=# coefficients).

Comment: You can estimate the noise in your data as being equal to the RMS of your residuals, but this assumes that the model is exact. I put "noise" in quotation marks because the residuals include everything the model failed to describe.

Comment: So,the residual noise is different from w(t) in the mathematical term used in https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/?q=node/60 and in other areas to represent an AR model?

Comment: It is different in the sense that your model may be imperfect, or one of the assumptions (listed under the equation for the AR model in the link you show) may be violated. But you can use the residuals to **estimate** w(t)

Comment: Should I write another question on how to estimate w(t) from residuals?

Comment: You could. If you do I would try the statistics list on stackexchange since that is not a matlab question, unless your question is "how do I compute the RMS noise in matlab" which I would answer with : `rms = sqrt(mean(residuals.^2))`

Answer (score 2):

If you model is simply `y(n)= a*y(n-1)` with scalar `a`, then here is the solution.

```
y = randn(10, 1);
a = y(1 : end - 1) \ y(2 : end);

y_estim = y * a;
residual = y - y_estim;
```

Of course, you should separate the data into train-test, and apply `a` on the test data. You can generalize this approach to `y(n)= a*y(n-1) + b*y(n-2)`, etc.

Note that `\` represents `mldivide()` function: [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)

**Edit:**

```
% model: y[n] = c + a*y(n-1) + b*y(n-2) +...+z*y(n-n_order)
n_order = 3;
allow_offset = true; % alows c in the model

% train
y_train = randn(20,1); % from your data
[y_in, y_out] = shifted_input(y_train, n_order, allow_offset);
a = y_in \ y_out;

% now test
y_test = randn(20,1); % from your data
[y_in, y_out] = shifted_input(y_test, n_order, allow_offset);
y_estim = y_in * a; % same a
residual = y_out - y_estim;
```

here is shifted_input():

```
function [y_in, y_out] = shifted_input(y, n_order, allow_offset)
y_out = y(n_order + 1 : end);
n_rows = size(y, 1) - n_order;
y_in = nan(n_rows, n_order);
for k = 1 : n_order    
    y_in(:, k) = y(1 : n_rows);
    y = circshift(y, -1);
end
if allow_offset
    y_in = [y_in, ones(n_rows, 1)];
end
return
```